# why spring-boot test by H2, but it write data to my local mysql db?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-test

Spring-boot version `1.5.3.RELEASE`;

`application-test.yml` 
file location: `../src/test/resources`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL
  profiles:
    active: test
```

and my test BaseClass is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = RestApiConfiguration.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BaseRestApiTest {

    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

}
```

and now in the test class which extends `BaseRestApiTest`, I post data to an URL like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/create`, and finally, the user data was written to my local MySQL DB.

```
@Test
    public void testAdd() {
        String url = HOST + "/api/user/create";
        Map<String, Object> form = Maps.newHashMap();
        form.put("userId", 1);

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(form.size());
        params.setAll(form);

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(params, httpHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<Long> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Long.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(resp.getBody());
    }
```

Expecting is the user data was just written in `H2` in the memory, but not my local MYSQL DB.

Answer (score 1):

Your BaseRestApiTest is already marked with @ActiveProfiles("test"), so all you need to have in your application-test.yml is following:

```
spring:
jpa:
    database: HSQL
```

and of a dependency, as in this sample, I used Gradle, so it is following line:

```
    testCompile group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb'
```

ofc, if you are using maven, you need to write it in maven format in your pom.xml file.